# Accelerate float calculations in nested loops (with CUDA if possible)

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Is it possible to accelerate the following nested loop in Python (possibly with CUDA or parallel process)? The order of the elements that are appended to `outputList[i]` doesn't matter.

Currently, the code takes a long time to complete. Which part is slowing down the code? Is it the `append()` or the calculation `f = c*sin(i*pi/180) + (1/c)*cos(i*pi/180)`?

```
N = 640*480
outputList = [[] for i in range(N)]

def foo(a,b): # a, b are always integers
    c = sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
    for deg in range(360):
        f = c*sin(deg*pi/180) + (1/c)*cos(deg*pi/180)
        if (f<1):
            outputList[a].append(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(N):
        for y in range(60):
            foo(x,y)
```

Comment: Surely you would just replace that function with a couple of lines of numpy code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As talonmies mentioned, your first step should be using numpy.

```
import math

import numpy as np

def foo(a, b):
    c = math.hypot(a, b)
    degs = np.arange(360, dtype='f8')
    rads = np.deg2rad(degs)
    fs = c * np.sin(rads) + (1/c)*np.cos(rads)
    below1 = fs[fs < 1.]
    outputList[a].extend(below1)
```

There are fancier methods to do the sin + cos computation but I've kept it simple for now. Also, depending on your use case, change outputList to a 2D numpy array or a list of 1D numpy arrays